# GraphQL - array among strings

Tags: web-scraping, graphql

I'm scraping a site that uses GraphQL, so I have no access to the source code.

In the query I'm specifying this (below) which fetches all relevant parameters:

```
parameters {
  key
  displayValue
  value
  __typename
}
```

The issue I'm faced with is that one of the parameters is actually an array so the 'value' value returns None (all other values work). I get INTERNAL SERVER ERROR:

```
{
    'message': 'String cannot represent value: ["item1", "item2", ... 30 more items]', 
    'locations': [{'line': 133, 'column': 5}],
    'path': ['path', 'to', 'node', 'value'],
    'extensions': {'code': 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR'}
}
```

Can I circumvent this without the access to the source code, query only?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply change the expected outcome of this query in your GraphQL schema:

```
type Query{
 ....
 exampleQuery : [String!]
}
```

Comment: I tried updating the query, adding `parameters: [String!]` but got `Syntax Error: Expected $, found Name "parameters"`. Adding the dollar sign changes 'parameters' to a variable, which is then not defined anywhere, so it threw `Variable "$parameters" is never used in operation "queryName".`